# Native winAPI in C++\CLI

Tags: .net, winapi, visual-c++, c++-cli

I started a new project with type of Windows Forms application, and I put two textboxes (textbox1 and textbox2) and a button. I used OpenFileDialog to select a file from the system and put it's path in textbox1, I put the following code for the button:

```
HANDLE hFile;
HANDLE hMap ;
LPVOID base;

hFile = ::CreateFile((LPCWSTR)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(this->textBox1->Text).ToPointer(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,0,OPEN_EXISTING , FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, 0);

unsigned long sifi= ::GetFileSize(hFile,NULL);

if(hFile !=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
hMap= ::CreateFileMapping(hFile, 0, PAGE_READONLY | SEC_COMMIT, 0, 0, 0);//create Mem mapping for the file in virtual memory
 }
if( hMap!=NULL){
base = ::MapViewOfFile(hMap, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);//load the mapped file into the RAM
                            }
this->textBox2->Text=sifi.ToString();
```

What I am trying to do with that code is to read the file path from textbox1 to use it for openning a file handle and then get the size of the file and put it into textbox2. The problem now is, textbox2 shows incorrect value of the file size. It seems always like 4294967295 for all files!

**Edit:**

Thanks guys, I have solved the problem. It was in the first parameter of CreateFile, it supposes to be:

```
(LPCWSTR)Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(this->textBox1->Text).ToPointer()
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the .net class for memory mapped files that was introduced in .net 4.0?

Comment: Yes but i already wrote it before .net 4.0 ,,btw would it be faster if i use .net class than native api?

Comment: It would be faster for you to get working code!  ;-)  I'd expect there to be little difference in performance.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: hi, actually there is a great difference in performance: in my machine, using the managed Memory-mapped file classes is 31 times slower than using the native API!  I measured this using both C++/CLI as well as unsafe C# pointers to the mapped view and they're both as fast.

Comment: Just a warning to future readers, the code which the question asserts "it supposes to be" has **a memory leak and no type safety**.  I strongly recommend using `PtrToStringChars` as my answer shows, not the `Marshal` class, for accessing the filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's recommended to use `GetFileSizeEx` instead of `GetFileSize`.  But  think your `CreateFile` call failed.

`CreateFile` doesn't accept an `HGLOBAL`.  And you're converting the string to ANSI, then passing it to a Unicode version of `CreateFile`, which is also broken.

Just stay in Unicode, like this:

```
pin_ptr<wchar_t> wszFilename = PtrToStringChars(textBox1->Text);
HANDLE hFile = ::CreateFileW(wszFilename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,0,OPEN_EXISTING , FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, 0);
if (hFile == 0 || hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) throw gcnew Win32Exception();
```

Answer (score 2):

The GetFileSize function is returing an error value.

> Note that if the return value is
>   INVALID_FILE_SIZE (0xffffffff), an
>   application must call GetLastError to
>   determine whether the function has
>   succeeded or failed.

See the [API docs on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364955%28VS.85%29.aspx).

By the way, I think @David Heffernan has a point here.